# Showing Not Acceptable 406 error in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am getting a new error and its first time I am facing such error. Whenever I submit form and if it contains '%' in any field, then it shows me the 406 Not Acceptable error. 
Also, when I submit the form and any field didn't contain '%' then form is successfully submitted. 
I have already tried adding

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

in database.php but it didn't work.
Also, I have found in R&D that by adding 'mysql_real_escape_string' in PHP,, this can be resolved. But ho it can be used in laravel..

Please help me out, 
Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page-inner"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @include('admin.partials.flash_message')                    
                        <form action="{{ $action }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf()
                        <?php /*@if(!empty($method)) @method($method) @endif*/ ?>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>RFP Title <span class="text-danger">*</span> :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rfp_title" value="{{ $pageTitle }}" {{ $prop }} maxlength="100">                                              
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>RFP Description <span class="text-danger">*</span> :</label> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textarea id="summernote" name="rfp_description"></textarea>
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">                      
                                        <label>Organisation <span class="text-danger">*</span> :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organisation" value="{{ $pageTitle }}" {{ $prop }} maxlength="100">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">                      
                                        <label>Publish Date <span class="text-danger">*</span> :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="publish_date" value="{{ $pageTitle }}" {{ $prop }} maxlength="100" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">                                       
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Closing Date <span class="text-danger">*</span> :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="closing_date" value="{{ $pageTitle }}" {{ $prop }} maxlength="100" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">                           
                                    <div class="col-md-3">                      
                                        <label>Company Image <span class="text-danger">*</span> :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="file" name="company_image" id="imageUpload" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" class="hide"> 
                                        <label for="imageUpload" class="upload-poster mr-5">Select file</label> Max Size 2 MB<br>
                                        <img src="{{ asset('public/assets/admin/images/dummy-logo.jpg')}}" id="imagePreview" class="organisation-logo" alt="Your image will appear here.">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">                                       
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>Attachment <span class="text-danger">*</span> :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="file" name="attachment" id="file-2" class="inputfile" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" multiple>
                                        <label for="file-2" class="mr-5"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/></svg> <span>Select File</span></label> Max Size 2 MB
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">                      
                                        <label>Contact Person :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_person" value="{{ $pageTitle }}" {{ $prop }} maxlength="100">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">                      
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="btn_btn_add_product"  {{ $prop }}>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you please share your HTML code of form so that we can see it's properties and field types? Moreover, you are getting HTML response which means the issue is in your HTTP Request.

Comment: I have added the code, check once